# How to get an integer result from the math floor function in golang?

Tags: go

The `math.Floor` in Golang returns a float64. But I would like it to return an integer. How can I get the integer value after performing the `floor` operation? Can I just use `int(x)` or `int32(x)` or `int64(x)`? I worry that the integer range might not match that of a float64 result therefore brings inaccuracy to the operation.

Answer (score 10):

**You may just want to check beforehand; if the conversion will perform safely or an overflow will occur.**

As [John Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102371/john-weldon) suggested,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var (
        a   int64
        f64 float64
    )

    // This number doesn't exist in the float64 world, 
    // just a number to perform the test.
    f64 = math.Floor(9223372036854775808.5) 
    if f64 >= math.MaxInt64 || f64 <= math.MinInt64 {
        fmt.Println("f64 is out of int64 range.")
        return
    }

    a = int64(f64)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

> [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1QEORXkli6)

I hope this will answer your question.
Also, I'd really like to know if any better solution is available. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can compare the float64 value with `math.MaxInt64` or `math.MinInt64` before doing the conversion.